# MySQL is running but not as a Service CentOS 7

Tags: mysql, services, centos-7

I need backup an old database to reinstall a CentOS 7.5 server. To do this I’m facing the problem that any MySQL password is not available. Due to this I try restore root password for MySQL following [this tutorial](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password/) (i already made this on several servers).

The problem is that `mysql` or `mysqld` is not available as service when I try with systemctl stop `mysql(d)` command or `/etc/init.d/mysql(d)` stop (I not using parenthesis is for evidence that I try `mysql` and `mysqld` with each command) but the service does not exist, I receive the error:

> "Unit mysqld.service could not be found."

And this:

> "Unit mysql.service could not be found."

Later I assume that MySQL is not running and try the command:

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

And I receive the error:

> "190903 15:23:00 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists"

I don't have idea what's happening, or how to stop this MySQL instance.

Answer (score 0):

Get the process ID and kill it.

Assuming there are no other MySQL instances bound to other ports, etc. then simply doing

```
sudo kill `pidof mysqld`
```

should work (I had to run it twice on my desktop).  If there was a process to try to kill, it generates no output.  When there is no mysqld process, it will generate some error output.

If there are other instances of MySQL on the same box that you can't kill off, then you can use tools like `lsof` to find the process ID of the one that has the specific port open, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! with top i found the pid and with kill 1079 the mysql stop. Thanks again :3